# Switching between childviewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a parent `UIViewController` that loads two different child `UIViewControllers`, **A** and **B**. To load **A**, I do:

```
    [self addChildViewController:A];
    [self.container addSubview:A.view];
    [A didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Then when I want to add **B**, I'll use the same code. My question is how to remove **A.** Is this all I need:

```
    [A removeFromParentViewController];
```

or do I also need to add `[A.view removeFromSuperview];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest scenario, adding a child to a container controller takes three steps:

1. Call addChildViewController: on the parent and pass the child as the argument       (for example, [self addChildViewController:childvc]).
2. Add the child controller’s view as a subview (for example, [self.view addSubview:childvc.view]).
3. Call didMoveToParentViewController: on the child with the parent as its argument (for example, [childvc didMoveToParentViewController:self]).

To remove a child view controller, the steps are almost (but not quite) mirrored:

1. Call willMoveToParentViewController: on the child, passing nil as the argument (for example, [childvc willMoveToParentViewController:nil]).
2. Remove the child controller’s view (for example, [childvc.view removeFromSuperview]).
3. Call removeFromParentViewController on the child (for example, [childvc removeFromParentViewController]).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to swap between controller a and b then you will also need to use this code, or something similar, found on the apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

```
- (void) cycleFromViewController: (UIViewController*) oldC
            toViewController: (UIViewController*) newC
{
    [oldC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];                        // 1
    [self addChildViewController:newC];

    newC.view.frame = [self newViewStartFrame];                       // 2
    CGRect endFrame = [self oldViewEndFrame];

    [self transitionFromViewController: oldC toViewController: newC   // 3
          duration: 0.25 options:0
          animations:^{
             newC.view.frame = oldC.view.frame;                       // 4
             oldC.view.frame = endFrame;
           }
           completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             [oldC removeFromParentViewController];                   // 5
             [newC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            }];
}
```

1. Starts both view controller transitions.
2. Calculates two new frame positions used to perform the transition animation.
3. Calls the transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion: method to perform the swap.
4. This method automatically adds the new view, performs the animation, and then removes the old view. The animation step to perform to get the views swapped.
5. When the transition completes, the view hierarchy is in its final state, so it finishes the operation by sending the final two notifications.